# Why does autocomplete vary with environment variables in /bin/bash

Tags: bash

Why does:

```
vi $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postact<TAB>
```

become

```
vi \$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactactivate
```

on ubuntu 20.04 and

```
vi $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactactivate
```

on macOS.  The Ubuntu version ruins autocomplete for this command.

macOS$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release

ubuntu$ echo ${BASH_VERSION}
5.0.17(1)-release

Comment: What shell (and what version) are you using on ubuntu and macos?

Answer (score 0):

You have the `bash-completion` package installed on Ubuntu. Its generic _filedir_xspec tab-completion handler blindly quotes all special characters in the completion string, without knowing whether they were quoted previously or not.

Use `vim "$VIRTUAL_ENV"/Tab` to work around this issue – or remove bash-completion entirely. (Or find a way to remove specifically just the completion handler for `vi`.)

Alternative trick: `vim $VIRTUAL_ENV/Ctrl+Alt+E` to perform inline expansion of the $VIRTUAL_ENV variable to whatever actual value it has, and *then* you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> without worrying about the variable.

Comment: vi "$VIRTUAL_ENV"/TAB just stripes the quotes off and throws in a \

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+E doesn't do anything (The machine is remote, I'm ssh'd in)